# How would I make a UITextField scrollable in swift when I make the text field a box?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextfield

I am making a larger text field for a description text box in xcode, and I have made the text alignment the top left of the box. However when the user types and gets to the end it goes off the text field and begins scrolling to the right. I want the text to fill up the box then scroll down as the user fills up the box. Is there any way to do this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var questionDirections: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        questionDirections.text = "Please elaborate on your question, the more accurate the description the better!"
        questionDirections.textAlignment = .left
}
```

When I set up the text field like this I want it to fill up the box and then scroll down as more text is added, but instead it scrolls to the right and does not fill up the box as if I left the box in its original form.

Comment: You want a UITextView (multi-line), not a UITextField (one line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UITextView instead:

```
@IBOutlet weak var questionDirections: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        questionDirections.text = "Please elaborate on your question, the more accurate the description the better!"
}
```

And it's alignment is automatic due to language direction.